# Insert fields after success payment

Tags: laravel

Hope you all have a good day..

At first i have a form that user should fill before redirect to PayTabs page for payment

But i don't need the form to be inserted in database before success payment

```
public function index(Request $request): RedirectResponse
 {
     $response = $this->request(
         url: 'https://secure-global.paytabs.com/payment/request',
         payload: $this->transactionPayload(
             amount: 0
         )
     );

    Transaction::create([
        'paytabs_transaction_reference' => $response->json()['tran_ref'] ?? null
    ]);

    Cart::where('opened', '=', 0)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->update(['paytabs_transaction_reference' => $response->json()['tran_ref'] ?? null]);
    
    $cart_id = Cart::latest()->first()->id;

    $payment = new Payment;
    
    $payment->cart_id     = $cart_id;
    $payment->country_id  = $request->input('country_id');
    $payment->delivery_id = $request->input('delivery_id');
    $payment->address     = $request->input('address');
    $payment->street      = $request->input('street');              
    $payment->home        = $request->input('home');
    $payment->email       = $request->input('email');

    $payment->save();

    return redirect()->away($response['redirect_url']);
  
}

public function return(Request $request): string
{
    $category = Category::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    
    $validSignature = $this->validateSignature($request->all());

    if ($validSignature) {
        if ($request->respStatus == 'A') {
            $transaction = Transaction::where('paytabs_transaction_reference', $request->tranRef)->first();
            $transaction->paid = true;
            $transaction->save();
            
            DB::table('carts')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('opened', 0 )->update(['opened' => 1]);

            return view('index', compact('category', 'products'))->with('success', 'Payment has been done successfully. Thank you!') . $request->respMessage;
        }
             return view('index', compact('category', 'products')) . $request->respMessage;
             
             
    } else {
        return 'Invalid  Transaction Signature';
    }
}
```

Here the form will be inserted even if he back from the next page

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('index') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
    .......
    </form>
```

That's my form should be to INDEX function to redirect to payment page

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Make A Validation To Your Form

Comment: Can you explain more please ?